# Access Ribbon OnAction

Tags: ms-access, ribbon

Below is my XML code

```
    <toggleButton id="CloseBtn" label = "Close" 
        size="large"
        imageMso="FrameDelete"
        onAction= "=InvoiceRibbon_Close()"
        getPressed="MyToggle"
        keytip="C"
        supertip= "Close current window."/>
```

By Function is Form code:

`Public Function InvoiceRibbon_Close() As Boolean`

It works on three computers.  Two have Office 2016 Access and one is Access 2016 run time only.  It does not work on the other two computers. Both are Access 2016 run time only.  All three 2016 Run time computers are new computers which is Windows 10.  Error message is attached.

[image]

The onAction function is inside Form VBA code.  Below are some testing I did.

1. If I move InvoiceRibbon_Close to Module, it works.
2. On module OnAction function, I still cannot call function which is inside Form by Call Forms("FormName").InvoiceRibbonTesting_Close.  Error message is still the same.
3. The function in Form works.  I used it for a while.
4. I want to keep the function in Form VBA.  I have hundreds Functions which is form related.  It will be a huge tasks to move it to Module

Comment: Standard procedure to do/check: 1. Do you have a broken reference on those two computers? 2. **De**compile and then compact your database before deploying. 3. Check detailed version/build of Microsoft Access/Runtime, maybe they are not the same and one makes trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the computers that fail, does ANY VBA code work? So, button code and what not - check if they work. If they don't work, then of course the Ribbon code will not work.

The other issue:
Check if you have a timer form running. Remember, the FANTASTIC idea you are using is to call functions in the form, and NOT USE horrible call backs which MUST be placed in standard code modules and thus are not attached to the given form in which 99% of the time we want code in that form to run and be used (say like any standard button code, but now you are using the ribbon. So, your setup is good and a high recommend approach.

Some things to check for this failure:
Does any VBA run at all? Check the trusted location settings.

Do you have a timer form running in the background. This is VERY but VERY VERY VERY important to check. What occurs with a timer form is that the form focus actually CHANGES to the the timer form while the timer code runs, and then returns back to whatever form currently has the focus. This is HUGE HUGE HUGE important since when you click on a ribbon button, it will FIRST TRY to run code in the current focused form's code module. This is good and great, since as you note that's were you have (and should) have that code that belongs to that form.

However, IF DURING THE TIME you click on the ribbon and the current forms focus changes (such as timer code, or other forms code running that MIGHT/MAYBE/COULD/PERHAPS/POSSBILE changes the forms focus to another?

Well, the Ribbon will look for and try to find that routine in the form with the CURRENT focus. A timer form running thus will change the form's focus, and if you click that button while the timer form code is running, then THAT FORM at THAT POINT in time actually has the focus, and thus the Ribbon will actually be attempting to find and run the function name in your ribbon in that timer form!!

You can quite quick test the above by removing for a test any timer forms you have running.

The other thing to look for is any kind of accidentally forms focus change. So, say a you recent added a sub form, or another navigation form or what not? Well, now the form you think that has the focus does not in fact have the focus, and thus the ribbon can't find the routine to run. This often happens when you say switch to a nice new computer, are using say the runtime. With a newer machine, often everything is running so much better and faster, that the FOCUS CHANGE you did not see much now occurs in a far more aggressive fashion.

The bottom line and thing you are looking for here is:
Does a un-expected form focus change occur. Say to some sub form that specifies a different ribbon, or some other small message or dialog or popup form that appeared un-expected. With any of these objects getting focus, then your main form with the code that the ribbon buttons call will not be found.

So, this is not a trusted location (ie: other VBA code works just fine), then next to check and test with is if any timer form is running (since as noted such forms VERY quick do get and rob the current forms focus away - and if you hit the ribbon at the same time while the timer code runs, then the focus change has also occurred, and thus the ribbon button will fail.

The above as a result ALSO means:
Don't have a timer form(s) if you can avoid as such.
The timer code if you have has to be VERY good and efficient code - it better get in, run VERY fast, and get out.

Don't have a aggressive timer interval. So, say some timer is to check and shut down access? Well, checking 10 times a second, or even once a second is OVER kill. Have it check say every 3 seconds.

Note that the above timer issue also often causes report print buttons to fail - you find that some blank form gets printed (and that blank form is in fact the timer form that temp had the focus when you hit your report print button.)